# Display child pages on parent page: 404 message overrules shortcode in page

Tags: 404-error, child-pages, genesis-theme-framework

I am trying to get a page to show a list of the child pages.
I am using the Foodie Pro theme on the Genesis framework.

I am using the following code to do so:

```
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
function wpb_list_child_pages() { 

    global $post; 

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );

    else
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

    if ( $childpages ) {
        $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('wpb_childpages', 'wpb_list_child_pages');
```

I've added the above to my `functions.php` and the `shortcode [wpb_childpages]` to the parent page.

When I preview the changes I have made to the parent page, after adding the `shortcode`, I can see the list of child pages.
However, when I go to the site itself, and click the page, I get the "Sorry, no content matched your criteria"-message.

Is another function overruling my function or what is going on?
And is it possible to change it?

Comment: I tested the same code on my site.It works on preview as well as on the site.

Comment: I know the code works, but not why it does not work on my site specifically. There must be a function in the Genesis framework or the Foodie Pro theme, that cancels the function out. Are you using a specific theme, @WisdmLabs?

Comment: Does anybody have any idea on what is going on with the above?